# Trouble with missing Reference after gameObject is destroyed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, destroy

In my game, the npc is suppose to attack and destroy a house, which is assigned as a target on the script, but when the house is destroyed, an error says that there's a missing reference, which i expected to happen...

But how can I fix this? Is there a way to disable the target variable after the gameObject is destroyed?

this piece of code is on the npc script

```
void Start () {

    force = 1000;
    enemyHealth = 100;
    enemyAttack = 20;
    enemyDefense = 2;
    bigFont= new GUIStyle();
    bigFont.fontSize = 20;

    target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
    targetHouse = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("house").transform;



    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
}
```

this is on the house script

```
void Update () {
    if(houseHp<= 0){
        Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag("house"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for `null` and avoid the problem.

```
GameObject temp = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("house");

if(temp != null)
   targetHouse = temp.transform;
```

So when the `house` is destroyed `FindGameObjectWithTag()` will return `null`.

Comment: i tried inserting this code but it's not working, just to clarify, see if im doing it right:

//i declare the variable temp
public GameObject temp;

//then assign its value at start
void Start () {
   temp = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("casa");
}

//the if statement must be inserted where?

note: im using FSMStates with enum

Comment: @GabrielFerraz `temp` should be declared right where I put it, inside a function like `Start()` or `Update()`. That means you would put my code wherever you already do this piece of code: `targetHouse = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("house").transform;`